# Bash for loop error

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying out a simple bash script using for loop, and kept getting the following error:

```
'/test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'/test.sh: line 2: `do
```

The following is the code that is being used...

```
for animal in dog cat elephant
do
    echo "There are ${animal}s.... "
done
```

However, when I tried on other machines.. it is working no problem. 
Please help.

Comment: does the file start with `#!/bin/sh` ?  I suspect its an inconsistancy between the shells that its running in.  You know what they say... it's easier to port a shell than a shell script

Comment: Check to see if there are Windows-style line endings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841235/why-do-i-get-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-do

Answer (score 3):

Your `test.sh` script has Windows-style line endings. The shell sees each `\r\n` sequence as a `\r` character at the end of the line.

The shell is seeing `do\r` rather than `do`. Since `\r` sends the cursor to the beginning of the line, that's why you're seeing the quotation mark at the beginning of the line. Try

./test.sh 2>&1 | cat -A

to see what's actually in the error message.

Filter your `test.sh` script through something like `dos2unix` to correct the line endings. (Be sure to read the man page first; `dos2unix`, unlike most text filters, overwrites its input file.)

This is a common problem on Cygwin. Did you use a Windows editor to create the script?

Comment: Also you can detect the offending chars using `cat -v test.sh`